# AWS Athena JSON Multidimentional Array Structure

Tags: sql, arrays, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

The JSON file has a structure like this:

```
"otherstuff" : "stuff",
"ArrayofArrays" : {
   "Array-1" : {
      "type" : "sometype",
      "is_enabled" : false,
      "is_active" : false,
      "version" : "version 1.1"
   },
   "Array-2" : {
      "type" : "sometype",
      "is_enabled" : false,
      "is_active" : false,
      "version" : "version 1.2"
   }
   ...
}
```

The query runs when with the following

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test2.table14 (
`otherstuff` string,
`ArrayofArrays` array<array<struct<version:string>>>
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
     'serialization.format' = '1' ) LOCATION 's3://bucket/folder/' TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

However when I run a basic preview table query I get the following error.

> HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value for field #: org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONArray

There is clearly an issue with the array of array.  I am unable to figure out what the structure should be. Do you know how to declair the multidimentional array for this structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON does not contain any array elements. So instead of an array, you have to use the map column type, to access this structure.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test14 (
  otherstuff string,
  ArrayofArrays map<string,struct<
     is_enabled:boolean,
     is_active:boolean,
     type:string,
     version:string
  >>
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.format' = '1' ) 
LOCATION 's3://bucket/'
```

You can access the map through the following query syntax:

```
select t.ArrayofArrays['array-1'] from test14 t
```

Comment: This seems to work.  I am not sure how to step through the N number of ArrayofArrays but I hopefully will be able to work that out.