# Amazon Athena - Nested JSON Read

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have the following json object structure

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "media": {
    "twitter": "",
    "facebook": "{\"id\":\"9999\",\"first_name\":\"abc\",\"last_name\":\"xyz\",\"name\":\"abc xyz\"}"
  }
}
```

and following is the  table definition

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Ext_JSON_data(
id string,
media map<string,struct<id:string,first_name:string,last_name:string,name:string,email:string>>
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (  
'serialization.format' = '1'
  )
LOCATION
  's3://bucket/folder/'
```

Can someone please help me to read this JSON data in Athena

Comment: you kinda missing one level abstraction, arent you? { id, media: { facebook : { id, first, last } } } in your media Map<> definition

Comment: Sorry i could not get your hint. can you please explain this a bit more in detail please

Comment: I do not have time to form proper answer, but your data snippet you show, there is data: { "id": "", "media": { "facebook": { "id": "", "name": "" }, "twitter": "" } } , in your Athena definition its like you assume { "id": "", "media": { "id": "", "name": "" } }

Comment: I guess you're looking for something like `json_parse` (https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_parse), correct?

Comment: i am looking for something like this thread and also tried same query but it is not working in my case
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553340/aws-athena-json-multidimentional-array-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a string based column in external table and applied below sample query on external table to get desired result.
It may help someone!!!

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Ext_JSON_data(
id string,
media string
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (  
'serialization.format' = '1'
  )
LOCATION
  's3://bucket/folder/'
```

below is the sample query:

```
WITH the_table AS (
SELECT CAST(social AS MAP(VARCHAR, JSON)) AS social_data
  FROM (
    VALUES
    (JSON '{
    "twitter": "",
    "facebook": "{\"id\":\"9999\",\"first_name\":\"abc\",\"last_name\":\"xyz\",\"name\":\"abc xyz\"}"}')
) AS t (social)    
)  
SELECT 
    first_level_key AS first_level_key
   ,json_extract_scalar(first_level_value,'$')
   ,json_extract_scalar(json_extract_scalar(first_level_value,'$'), '$.id')
   ,json_extract_scalar(json_extract_scalar(first_level_value,'$'), '$.first_name')
  FROM the_table
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST (social_data) AS t (first_level_key, first_level_value)
```